# Parsing user input

Tags: python-3.x, string, parsing

How do I extract the date from a user input (Month, Day, Year) using the slicing method. The problem could be the way I slice the strings. Please enlighten me.

Here's a sample of my code. I can't seem to properly get the month and day right. I added `[0:9]` because I was thinking that September has 9 letters in it but the problem would be if the user input a month below than 9 letters then my code is screwed.

```
def extractDate(datevalue):
    d = datevalue
    return d

x = extractDate(input("Enter Date: "))
cpos = x.find(',')

print("Month: " + x[0:9])
print("Day: " + x[11:13])
print("Year: " + x[cpos+2:])
```

Output:

```
Enter Date: December 2, 1999
Month: December 
Day:  1
Year: 1999

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The expected output should be for example:

Month: December

Day: 2

Year: 1999

Comment: Is using slices *required*? Because it seems like a very unreliable way to approach the problem (as you point out as part of the question).

Comment: @SethMMorton yes, and without using any built-in date related functions. The only problem I have I think is the Month and Day. User input will always be: Month day, year (ex. December 2, 1999).

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed the input will always be like this you can do:

```py
def extract_date(date_string):
    month_day, year = date_string.split(", ")
    month, day = month_day.split(" ")
    return day, month, year
```